# Getting Error "Developer License Expired" while installing windows 8.1 App in Windows 10 OS

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have build a Win-rt app in Windows 8.1 which while installing in Windows 10 OS giving an error saying

```
Developer License Expired
```

Has anyone came across similar error or knows the solution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

feature with Windows 10 developer unlock model, you can visit the instructions here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Dn706236.aspx.

Comment: Thanks Midhun, i saw the the link but it does not solve my issue of "Developer License" related to Winrt 8.1 app installation in windows 10 as shared above